# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: react-native

I'm having this issue with ui kitten kit library, it works fine with regular but throw this error when I'm passing props. I tried to change my import / exports method with no luck. can please someone help figure it out.

```
import { RkTheme, RkButton, RkCard, RkText, rkCardContent, rkCardImg, rkCardFooter, } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

...

export default class AutocompleteExample extends Component {
render() {
  return (
  <Content />
    <RkCard>
  <View rkCardHeader>
    <Text>Header</Text>
  </View>
  <Image rkCardImg source={{uri: this.state.img}}/>
  <View rkCardContent>
    <Text>quick brown fox</Text>
  </View>
  <View rkCardFooter>
    <Text>{this.state.price}</Text>
  </View>
</RkCard>

 )
}

module.exports = AutocompleteExample
```

this.state.img works well and I'm able to see the picture however this.state.price do not work, if replace it with a regular text it works. Thanks.

Comment: Please confirm that the type of price is string or initialise it with an empty string.

Comment: @jainzz the json return some text like "close" and for price it return like 123

Comment: Convert it into string :)

Comment: @jainzz I tried {this.state.price}.toString() don't work

Comment: {this.state.price.toString()} may help

Comment: @JainZz undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.price.toString')

Comment: Added sample code as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the above code

```
import { RkTheme, RkButton, RkCard, RkText, rkCardContent, rkCardImg, rkCardFooter, } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

...

export default class AutocompleteExample extends Component {

state = {
  price: '',
}

render() {
  return (
  <Content />
    <RkCard>
  <View rkCardHeader>
    <Text>Header</Text>
  </View>
  <Image rkCardImg source={{uri: this.state.img}}/>
  <View rkCardContent>
    <Text>quick brown fox</Text>
  </View>
  <View rkCardFooter>
    <Text>{this.state.price}</Text>
  </View>
</RkCard>

 )
}

module.exports = AutocompleteExample
```

Comment: it work without the .toString() thing if I initialize with empty string in state. Thanks!

Comment: Thats what I told in first comment :)